# Sizing two BarButtonItem in the rightBarButtonItems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

How can I do something like this:

[image]

I tried to changed through setframe  and nothing happened:

```
UIImage *flechSuiv = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picto_fleche_lieux_suiv.png"];

UIButton *buttonSuiv =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttonSuiv setImage:flechSuiv forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonSuiv addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[buttonSuiv setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 34+flechSuiv.size.width, flechSuiv.size.width,flechSuiv.size.height)];


self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:barButtonSuiv,barButtonPrec,nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for a custom navigation bar. You'd need to hide the navigation bar before presenting the view.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

And put an UIView matching the size of a regular tab bar in your view controller.
Inside of that view, you can put any custom buttons with regular action (push or pop).